# SharePoint lists stores US dates incorrectly

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I have an InfoPath form on SharePoint used by both UK and US users. One of the fields is a date picker field.

If a US user enters the 9th Feb as the date it is stored in the list (which is on a UK timezone server) as **02/09/15** (i.e. 2nd September). If a UK user enters 9th Feb it would be stored as **09/02/15**.

What can I do about this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you double checked the Sites' Regional Settings (in Site Settings)

Comment: Yes. Timezone: London. Locale: UK

Comment: Your tags are confusing. Please edit them to specify whether it is SP online / foundation or server. All 3 are different flavors of SP.

Comment: Are users entering the dates or choosing them? If they are entering it by themselves, what is happening is expected behavior. If US users enter the dates thinking that 2nd Feb is 2/9/15, SP takes it as UK format (2nd Sep) and displays.

Comment: They could be typing it in manually, despite the fact the field is labelled (DD/MM/YYYY). Is there any way of turning off the text entry box and forcing use of the calendar pop-up?

Comment: If it is fine with you, you can add a validation rule on submit which stops from submitting if the date entered is greater than today but that would mean users won't be able to add forms with dates greater than today.

Comment: @wjervis it's an infopath form. JS wont work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the regional settings of the user are set correctly.

You can check the regional settings of the user in their my-site (or user profile).